# Instrument amplifier output continuing drifting

Tags: instrumentation-amplifier, load-cell

I'm using AD8226 to amplifier differential signal coming out of a load cell, the output of the AD8226 goes straight into the AD7190. My load cell is full bridge with output impedance of 350 Ohm, excited by 5V.

Here is my schematic for the AD8226.

[image]

The IN1- and IN1+ is connected to the load cell. Here is just one channel, there are four channels of these. All share the same 5V with four load cells. The 5V is generated by MIC5205-5.

The schematic of Vbias is down below. All four channel share the same Vbias.

[image]

The simulation in LTSpice seems fine. However, as I receive the PCB and test it, I found that the output of the AD8226 is continuing drifting.

The output of the AD8226 is continuing rising, about 0.1mV per second. I test another channel, the output of that channel is continuing falling by the same rate. And I leave it there for a while and one channel just broken. Why is that happened?

All the component in the board is SMT except for the AD8226 and 249ohm gain setting resistor. And all the resistor is 1% and all the capacitor is 10%.

The load cell is connected to the board by a screw terminal, and some channels are not always connected to a load cell.

Comment: Does it drift if something other than the load cell is connected to the input? A dummy bridge, for example?

Comment: I connected a signal generator to the input and it still drifting.

Comment: And it's just drifting in one direction until it saturates?

Comment: Before saturated, at some point, the output is just floating around.

Comment: The ground of your load cell excitation source is  connected to the ground of your AD8226 power supply right? Also check your PCB for broken solder joints.

Comment: The ground is right, and I tried to re-solder the ad8226, switch to another channel, the problem still the same.

Comment: @livecf Well, there is one small problem. The AD8226 wants a reference voltage with 2 Ohms or less output impedance and the AD8541 shows a typical of 50 Ohms. And you've got all your AD8226 tied to just the one output? (This might at least provide a partial explanation how one output might seem inversely related to another.) I think a better question for you right now is to ask for advice about isolating this problem rather than solving it. How better to go about dividing and conquering this issue?

Comment: @livecf The fact that the output drifts around, perhaps at first along a slope but then just wandering around, suggests to me some trace currents leaking onto some trace capacitance but where once the voltage gets a little higher the trace currents are compensated by leakage responding to the new voltage output (or something related to it.) Do you use driven guard traces? (It's late at night and I should be off to bed. So I may just be wondering out loud.)

Comment: @jonk I didn't use guard traces. If it is what you said, would it help if I de-solder all the capacitor on the input?

Comment: @livecf You may want to "dead bug" something. Probably should have done that before going to a board, in fact. (It's what I do, anyway.) That way you have a reference that "just works right" to go from. (Or it doesn't and you keep at it until you get it right.) If there is a reason you slapped those capacitors down, then I suppose they should be there. But if you feel you can remove them, then perhaps they shouldn't be there and you should try removing them to see if it affects anything. Anyway, I really do need to get to bed now.